# Error occurs when using DEBUG=express:* npm start command in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

When I try to run DEBUG=express:* npm start command on **Windows** then error occurs as follow:

```
 'DEBUG' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I have already searched for solution on similar topic on stackoverflow but none of them work for me.

I have tried following things:

**1.** I installed debug library: **npm install debug**

**2.** set DEBUG=express:* & node bin/www

It gives error:

```
                    Error: Cannot find module '../app'
                    Require stack:
                    - C:\Users\leo\notes\bin\www
```

If  someone knows  knows how to handle it then please share your answer.

My www file code is:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env node

  /**
   * Module dependencies.
  */

  var app = require('../app');
  var debug = require('debug')('notes:server');
  var http = require('http');

  /**
  * Get port from environment and store in Express.
  */

  var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
  app.set('port', port);

  /**
   * Create HTTP server.
  */

  var server = http.createServer(app);

  /**
  * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
  */

 server.listen(port);
 server.on('error', onError);
 server.on('listening', onListening);

 /**
  * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

 function normalizePort(val) {
    var port = parseInt(val, 10);

    if (isNaN(port)) {
       // named pipe
       return val;
    }

    if (port >= 0) {
        // port number
        return port;
    }

   return false;
  }

 /**
  * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

 function onError(error) {
    if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
       throw error;
    }

    var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

    // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
    switch (error.code) {
          case 'EACCES':
               console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
               process.exit(1);
          break;
          case 'EADDRINUSE':
               console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
               process.exit(1);
          break;
          default:
      throw error;
     }
   }

 /**
   * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

  function onListening() {
     var addr = server.address();
     var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
     ? 'pipe ' + addr
     : 'port ' + addr.port;
     debug('Listening on ' + bind);
  }
```

When I changed **var app = require('../app');** to **var app = require('../app.mjs');** in **www** file then I got other error:

```
           C:\Users\leo\notes>set DEBUG=express:* & node bin/www
           internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983
           throw new ERR_REQUIRE_ESM(filename);
           ^
```

The content of **package.json** file is:

```
{
  "name": "notes",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
   "scripts": {
   "start": "cross-env DEBUG=notes:* node ./app.mjs",
   "server1": "cross-env DEBUG=notes:* PORT=3001 node ./app.mjs",
   "server2": "cross-env DEBUG=notes:* PORT=3002 node ./app.mjs"
    },
    "dependencies": {
         "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
         "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
         "debug": "~2.6.9",
         "express": "^4.17.1",
         "hbs": "^4.0.6",
         "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
         "morgan": "^1.9.1"
    }
  }
```

Comment: How are you requiring your `app` file? It appears that when your `bin/www` script is run, it's looking in the wrong place.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45852255/13126651 does this help?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra no, I have already tried it

Comment: Where is your app.js file relative to bin/www?

Comment: @Phix my app.mjs file is outside the bin folder

Answer (score 1):

It seems that 'debug' library is not installed. Install using the following command and try again.

```
npm install debug
```

Comment: DEBUG is an environment variable. It was not working the first time as that's the syntax for nix based system, Leo is on windows.